# phpunit test returns 302 for bad validation, why not 422

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

I have a request class that fails for a post request. When I call it with ajax I get an 422 because the validation rules failed. But when I use phpunit for test for the same route with same values, it returns a 302.

I also get no error messages like "field foobar is required" just the 302.

So how can I get the error messages to check if they are equals or not?

Here is my testcode:

```
//post exam
$this->post('modul/foo/exam', [
    'date' => '2016-01-01'
])
    ->assertResponseStatus(200);

//post exam again
$this->post('modul/foo/exam', [
    'date' => '2016-01-01'
])
    ->assertResponseStatus(302); //need to get 422 with th errors because its an api
```

Comment: If you use ajax, failed validation returns a 422. If you don't, failed validation returns a 302 redirect. Your test either needs to make the request as ajax, or follow the redirect. We can't help further because you didn't post any code, show your test, etc.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

When the validation on the `FormRequest` fails, it checks to see if the request was ajax or if it accepts a json response. If so, it will return a json response with the 422 status code. If not, it will return a redirect to a specified url (previous, by default). So, in order to get the response on failure you're looking for (422), you need to make a json request or an ajax request.

#### JSON

To make a json request, you should use the `json()` method:

```
//post exam
$this->json('POST', 'modul/foo/exam', [
        'date' => '2016-01-01'
    ])
    ->assertResponseStatus(200);

//post exam again
$this->json('POST', 'modul/foo/exam', [
        'date' => 'some invalid date'
    ])
    ->assertResponseStatus(422);
```

There are also `getJson()`, `postJson()`, `putJson()`, `patchJson()`, and `deleteJson()` shortcut methods if you think that looks cleaner than passing the method as a parameter.

```
//post exam
$this->postJson('modul/foo/exam', [
        'date' => '2016-01-01'
    ])
    ->assertResponseStatus(200);
```

#### AJAX

To make an ajax request, you need to add in the ajax headers. For this, you can continue to use the `post()` method:

```
//post exam
$this->post('modul/foo/exam', [
        'date' => '2016-01-01'
    ], ['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' => 'XMLHttpRequest'])
    ->assertResponseStatus(200);

//post exam again
$this->post('modul/foo/exam', [
        'date' => 'some invalid date'
    ], ['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' => 'XMLHttpRequest'])
    ->assertResponseStatus(422);
```

Comment: It worked. Also stetting a header with `'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'`works fine with `normal $this->post`

Comment: @patricus thanks mate. I've been trying to solve this issue past 8 hours but couldn't figure it out. $this->json was the key. +1

Comment: Fought this battle upgrading from a Lumen based application to Laravel. In testing $this->get() must have always assumed JSON for lumen requests, not so in Laravel tests.

Answer (score 4):

For Laravel 6 this works:

```
withHeaders(['Accept' => 'application/json'])
```

For an example:

```
 $this->withHeaders(['Accept' => 'application/json'])
     ->post(route('user.register'), $data)
     ->assertStatus(422)
     ->assertJson($expectedResponse);
```

If it's needed for multiple test classes, it can be placed in `tests/TestCase.php` and it will be set up for all test cases.

For an example:

```
public function setup(): void
{
    $this->withHeaders([
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'
    ]);
}
```

Those headers set in `tests/TestCase.php` can be extended at any point by the same way. For an example:

```
$this->withHeaders([
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$responseArray['access_token']
]);
```